# What to do about an answer that sounds harmful to your car?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/45936) is a late answer to a question, and I came across it in review. However the answer is from a low rep user (with 1 reputation) and I don't like the sound of this answer.

Putting corrosive oven cleaner in the intakes sounds bad for the engine

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your assessment as to it being bad advice. The best thing you can do on this answer is to downvote and comment as to why you believe it is bad advice. Just remember in doing so to "be nice" about it. While it may be bad advice, it is still an answer. If it were a good answer, we'd be upvoting it. Since it's bad, all we can expect is to downvote with comment. We have to rely on the voting system to denote bad advice.

Ultimately, the decision is yours as to how to handle it from your point of view. Please realize what I've stated here is my "opinion", as you've always got the final say as to how to vote and how to respond. If you feel the answer is totally egregious, you can always mention it at [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) where you can make it known there's a possible issue. If others agree with your assessment, it'll get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a comment asking for references and that I'm happy to be proven wrong as this does sound interesting and could provoke a discussion about how or why it works? It it does that is haha

Comment: @George - Sounds good to me :o)

Comment: On a related note, if the answer is sufficiently downvoted, it will become mostly invisible to general users. The chat room is also a great place to socialize a questionable answer: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop